# Is it possible to upload ipa file in istore if i open website url in brower on click event of ipa file

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I have created one .ipa file using `PhoneGap`.

When user click on my App Icon, it will redirect user to my website in web browser.

Will AppStore approve this ind of App.

**Another Doubt:**
Also, If I use WebKit Component in my App to show the Website inside the App; Will Apple approve this kind of App ?

Comment: Hello Viral, Thanks for your prompt reply. But is there any option to upload this type of application. Like if i use Child browser and open that website than will iStore allow me to upload my ips file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through this [AppStore Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#functionality):

It says:

[image]

AND

[image]

Hope this clears your concerns.

So, If your are **not** doing **anything useful** and **entertaining**, other than showing the website in web view or providing external links to your web sites; then you should be ready to get **rejection**.

Comment: Hi Viral. Thanks for your prompt reply. I appreciate your ans.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple Review guideline , only website embed in iOS App with `UIWebView` or Redirect to website and not useful app will be reject.

Comment: I have created on Online education application website so will iStore approve that website.

Comment: you only embed your Website in your iOS App? Or Is there others functions?

Comment: Only Authorize user can login in that website. User has to create his/her account as new user. After that Admin must has to Authorize that user than only he/she can login in the application.